# Install Android SDK in apple silicon

Tags: android, docker, dockerfile, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-manager

I am installing SDK in a Docker from macOS Apple silicon using the following command in my Dockefile:

```
RUN sdkmanager "platforms;android-33" "build-tools;33.0.0" "platform-tools"
```

Unfortunately that's not working properly and when I run a command such as `adb`. I get the following error:

```
rosetta error: failed to open elf at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
 Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Is there a way to install sdk android-33 for arm architecture?